# Loess Fit and Resulting Equation

Tags: r, curve-fitting, loess

I'm a developer up in Portland, OR. I'm wondering if anyone can assist:

I'm working on Loess fit models using R, once I have the fit
accomplished, I'm looking to back-out the equation of the
fitted non-linear curve, wondering if there is a way to
determine this equation in R? I've been looking but can't find
any literature. For me, the graph of the function is great, but
without the equation of the graph, I'm kinda dead in the water.

Comment: Did you ever come up with an alternative to your approach?

Answer (score 14):

Loess doesn't give you an equation [1]. If you just want to get the values returned by the loess function you use `predict(loess.object, new.data)`

[1] From wikipedia:

> Another disadvantage of LOESS is the
>   fact that it does not produce a
>   regression function that is easily
>   represented by a mathematical formula.
>   This can make it difficult to transfer
>   the results of an analysis to other
>   people. In order to transfer the
>   regression function to another person,
>   they would need the data set and
>   software for LOESS calculations.

Comment: correct, it doesn't give you a mathematical formula, but it gives you a graph. I want to find a formula for the graph given.

Comment: You can't. Loess uses an iterative local approach and is data-driven, see the reference papers for details.

Comment: Do you have suggestions for another approach? The loess returns a "equivalent number of parameters" for each model developed. I am interested in adjusting any of the parameters to play with the fit of the model.

Answer (score 8):

There is no formula. Loess is a nonparametric method. It can't be expressed as a simple equation.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot extract the formula from LOESS itself. However, you could simply run another method on the points found by LOESS. If it's a simple 2D graph then it shouldn't be that hard to find a good formula. One method for doing this is symbolic regression (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_regression)).

Be aware that this is probably not optimal and it might be better to simply use another method than LOESS.

Answer (score 0):

You want to recover the formula from a loess object?  You might be able to do something like this:

```
> cars.lo <- loess(dist ~ speed, cars)
> formula(unclass(cars.lo)$terms)
dist ~ speed
```

*Edit:* Sorry...I think that I misinterpreted what you wanted.  There is no simple way to express the loess model in the form of an equation.