# Scatterplot:car extracting fits

Tags: r, plot, lines, r-car

Is there a way to extract functions that are used when you plot with `scatterplot`6 from car?

Example:

> require(car)
>
> [scatterplot(x~y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYpNZ.jpg)

What it produces by default is a `scatterplot` with four lines, one for linear regression, 2 for residuals, and one (full red line) for a function that fits the data.

Now I want to know which function is used to produce the red line. Not this specific one, but generally is there a way to obtain this function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loess Fit and Resulting Equation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785118/loess-fit-and-resulting-equation). See `?scatterplot` and the `smoother` argument: "the default is `loessLine`, which does `loess` smoothing"

Comment: I really don't think this falls under exact duplicate.  They are't looking to express it in closed form - they just want the function.  Voting to Leave Open.