# R - Approximate Equation for set of points

Tags: r

I have two vectors `x` and `y`.

```
y <- c(0.0575, 0.1137, 0.2018, 0.3228, 0.5331, 0.8771, 1.0000)
x <- c(0.0040, 0.0105, 0.0258, 0.0540, 0.1210, 0.3419, 1.0000)
```

Which I can easily plot the relationship between them.

```
plot(y~x)
```

[image]

Is there any means by which I can get an approximate equation for the relationship between these vectors?

I can fit a `loess` line but that doesn't allow me to extract the equation.

```
lo <- loess(y~x)
```

I only am looking for an approximation but I am not sure how to accomplish this within R.

Comment: According to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785118/loess-fit-and-resulting-equation), you cannot get an equation from a loess fit.

Comment: @emilliman5, thank you but I guess I didn't make it clear at the end of my question that I realize that you can't get the equation from `loess`.  I am wondering if there is some other approach to this problem.