# Put equation for a ggplot2 : stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, non-linear-regression

How could you place the equation that fits the points?

```
ggplot(data=iris) +
  geom_point( aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length,color=Species)) +  
  stat_smooth(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length),method = "loess")
```

[image]

Comment: `loess` regression doesn't produce an equation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785118/loess-fit-and-resulting-equation

Comment: If you wanted to do a linear model, then this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph. but as already mentioned, loess doesn't create a simple equation that you can right down easily; it's a smoothing technique, not really for model fitting